# Swift: Location manager not updating location?

Tags: ios

I'm trying to implement GoogleMaps but I can't even get the CLLocationManager to work. The `didUpdateLocations` method isn't being run. This is my controller:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import GoogleMaps

...

class RootMapViewController: UIViewController {

  let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

  @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchLocation()

    ...
  }

  func addMapPin(coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String, description: String) {
    ...
  }

  private func fetchLocation() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
  }

  private func centerMapOn(userCoordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    ...
  }

}

// MARK: CLLocationManagerDelegate

extension RootMapViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

  func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
      print("gggggggggggggggggg") // <----------------- prints properly **** 
      locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
      print("hhhhh")
      mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
      mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    }
  }

  // ISSUE ARISES HERE: *****************************************
  func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    print("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz") // <----------------- doesn't print ****
    let userCoordinates = manager.location!.coordinate
    centerMapOn(userCoordinates)
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
  }

}
```

My Info.plist file has the key:

[image]

Update:

[image]

Comment: Try actually typing something for the nslocationwheninuseusagedescription

Comment: no luck... i even added the other one (updated the question with the screenshot)

Comment: Does/did the alert show up?

Comment: nope. i only see the `print("gggg")` in `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` but i don't see the actual alert

Comment: When you go into settings->privacy->location services does your app say while in use or always next to it?

Comment: Are you testing on simulator or device?

Comment: simulator. let me try with a device

Comment: it works on my device!!! hallelujahhhhhhh thanks so much. not sure why the simulator is so crappy

Comment: Yeah. The simulator can be kind of flakey. Sometimes changing the location to a custom location or clicking Apple can cause it to kick into gear but lots of times it just does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call

```
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation;
```

on the last line of fetchLocation() function.